# Nature of plasma of the early intergalactic medium

Tags: cosmology, plasma-physics

Please I have a question to ask about the nature of plasma of the early intergalactic medium at large redshifts.

We known that the most important **unmagnetized** cosmic plasma is the early intergalactic medium. Please, is the plasma of the hadron epoch  ( 10^−6 s < time < 1 s after Big Bang) quantum (degenerate) or classic?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Please, is the plasma of the hadron epoch ( $10^{−6} s < time < 1 s$  after Big Bang) quantum (degenerate) or classic?

That is called the ["quark epoch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_epoch) , and just the use of the word "quark" indicates quantum mechanics,

> During the quark epoch the universe was filled with a dense, [hot quark–gluon plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma), containing quarks, leptons and their antiparticles. Collisions between particles were too energetic to allow quarks to combine into mesons or baryons.

, because quark are independent of nucleons only in a quark gluon plasma:

Comment: From Wikipedia:"The quark epoch ended when the universe was about 10^−6 seconds old, ....The following period, when quarks became confined within hadrons, is known as the hadron epoch." @anna v, my plasma is that of this era, hadron era (at 10^−6 seconds), is it also quantum?

Comment: of course, your time period is included in the quantum mechanical plasa